# Easiest way to get AWS Credential in an Android project using Java?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to send message to my SQS queue with my own account. It's easy to perform in others desktop sdk wih my access_key and secret access_key provided. While in an android project it's hard to initialise the environment. For example, I would like to implement the following codes to create a function `SendSQS`:

```
public void addItemSQS() {
    AmazonSQSAsyncClient sqs = new AmazonSQSAsyncClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance());
    sqs.setRegion(Region.getRegion("XX-XXXX-X"));
    SendMessageRequest req = new SendMessageRequest("https://sqs.XX-XXXX-X.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/MyQueue", "hello world");
    sqs.sendMessageAsync(req, new AsyncHandler<SendMessageRequest, SendMessageResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendMessageRequest request, SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "SQS result: " + sendMessageResult.getMessageId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "SQS error: ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to setup `AWSMobileClient.getInstance()` properly to grant the access to my SQS queue. I've tried `AmazonSQSAsyncClient(AWSCredentials awsCredentials)` method but got stuck with ininitialising AWSCredentials. `com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials` worked neither.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am stuck at this point. I know it's been a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Whats is the error?
From AWS docs:
Direct AWS Service access
You can call AWS service interface objects directly via the generated SDK clients.

> You can use the client credentials provided by the AWSMobileClient by
>   calling AWSMobileClient.getInstance() and passing it to the service
>   client. This will leverage short term AWS credentials from Cognito
>   Identity.
>
> To work with service interface objects, your Amazon Cognito users’ IAM
>   role must have the appropriate permissions to call the requested
>   services.

For example, if you were using Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) in your Android project you would first add aws-android-sdk-sqs:2.11.+ to your app/build.gradle and install the dependencies by running a Gradle Sync.

Next, import AmazonSQS in your Android Studio project and create the client

Also, what error did you got at the end?

Comment: however `AWSMobileClient.getInstance()` didn't work and nothing showed up in my queue. So I was guessing some properties of AWSMobileClient may need to be set first.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Me

```
public void sendingMessage(){
            AWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("ACCESS_ID","SECRET_KEY");
            AmazonSQSAsyncClient sqs =  new AmazonSQSAsyncClient(basicAWSCredentials);
            sqs.setRegion(Region.getRegion("region"));
            SendMessageRequest req = new SendMessageRequest("Queue URL","HELLO WORLD");
            sqs.sendMessageAsync(req, new AsyncHandler<SendMessageRequest, SendMessageResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Exception exception) {
                    System.out.println("Exception occured: "+exception.getMessage());
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SendMessageRequest request, SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
    
                    System.out.println("Message Sent: "+sendMessageResult.getMessageId());
                }
            });

        System.out.println("Ended");

    }
```